# Docker debian image containner apt update ocurs some problem

Tags: docker, debian, apt

Docker Hub pull debian:stable image, but using apt update command ocurs some problems

Docker Hub debian:stable image

### sources.list

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates main

Error Message:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable Release
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main all Packages
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
  SECURITY: URL redirect target contains control characters, rejecting. [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  SECURITY: URL redirect target contains control characters, rejecting. [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Do you have proxy? And what's the command you use? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: command: apt-get update , then problems ocur